# InvalidSignatureException when using boto3 for dynamoDB on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, python-3.4, boto3

Im facing some sort of credentials issue when trying to connect to my dynamoDB on aws. Locally it all works fine and I can connect using env variables for `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` and then

```
dynamoConnection = boto3.resource('dynamodb', endpoint_url='http://localhost:8000')
```

When changing to live creds in the env variables and setting the endpoint_url to the dynamoDB on aws this fails with:

> "botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the Query operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."

The creds are valid as they are used in a different app which talks to the same dynamoDB. Ive also tried not using env variables but rather directly in the method but the error persisted. Furthermore, to avoid any issues with trailing spaces Ive even used the credentials directly in the code. Im using Python v3.4.4.

Is there maybe a header that also should be set that Im not aware of? Any hints would be apprecihated.

EDIT

Ive now also created new credentials (to make sure there are only alphanumerical signs) but still no dice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `endpoint_url` when you are connecting to the real DynamoDB service.  That's really only for connecting to local services or non-standard endpoints.  Instead, just specify the region you want:

```
dynamoConnection = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')
```

Answer (score 2):

`sudo hwclock --hctosys` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It sign that your time zone is different. Maybe you can check your:
1. Time zone
2. Time settings.

If there are some automatic settings, you should fix your time settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to point out that accessing **DynamoDB** from a **C# environment** (using `AWS.NET SDK`) I ran into this error and the way I solved it was to create a new pair of AWS *access/secret keys*.
Worked immediately after I changed those keys in the code.